# Publishing series of photos on non-dynamic website

Tags: looking-for-a-script, photo-gallery

I have a series of photos I was asked to publish on a website. Website is on the free hosting  (plain HTML and ftp access). Is there any way (javascript framework or anything) to quickly build a gallery, without creating pages manually for each photo category? Or, probably, an offline tool to generate html-structure for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Jalbum](http://jalbum.net/en/) is probably the most popular application to do this. It is a small Java app that you run and produces a series HTML files even resizing your images if needed. You then simply upload the results to your server. It is very flexible with themes and plenty of optional settings to tweak things as you like it. I've used it for both personal and professional sites and it is really polished and extremely simple to use.

Answer (score 0):

Several photo editor apps have an export option to publish photos as an HTML gallery, including [Adobe Bridge,](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/Bridge/3.0/WSCF044571-2772-4d28-9EBD-2C9F46AF008A.html) [Aperture,](http://www.oreillynet.com/digitalmedia/blog/2007/01/create_a_web_gallery_in_apertu.html) and [Adobe Lightroom](http://www.adobe.com/designcenter/lightroom/articles/lir1at_publishgallery_print.html). You can probably find free alternatives to these by searching [iusethis.com](http://iusethis.com) for "web gallery".

You might also consider uploading your photos to a hosted service like [Flickr](http://www.flickr.com), collecting them into a [photo set,](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6NDwsOTlslo) then embedding that set in an html page on your own site as a [Flickr slideshow.](http://paulstamatiou.com/how-to-quickie-embedded-flickr-slideshows)